# Calling dismiss() on an Android Dialog that instantiates a new Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I was wondering if when using a Dialog/Fragment Dialog to instantiate a new Activity/Fragment is it programatically correct to call dialog.dismiss() or will it automatically occur?

For example:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
final CustomDialogFragment dialog = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance(
                            "Continue / Checkout",
                            "Would you like to continue shopping or proceed to checkout",
                            "Continue Shopping", "Checkout");
                    dialog.show(fm, "checkout_dialog_fragment");
                    dialog.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                    Dialog d = dialog.getDialog();
                    Button leftButton = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    Button rightButton = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);

                    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // DOES THIS DISMISS HAVE TO BE CALLED??
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            mListener.onFragmentRequestGoToBasket();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't expressively need to as whichever activity you are starting afterwards will dismiss it.

`dismiss()` just removes the Dialog from the viewstack, it does not delete all underlying references to Dialog objects.

While I would say you don't *need* to do it, I still would, if not for performance for better readability by other developpers.

The [Android Reference on Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog) explains both of these points.